# parallel ping using gevent

Tags: python, gevent

I am new to python and I am trying to run this code to want parallel ping of multiple machines.but I can not ping all IP concurrently. seems it run one after another .can some one please guide me on how can i ping multiple server concurrently.

```
import gevent
import urllib2
import os
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()


def print_head(i):
    switch='192.168.182.170'
    response = os.system("ping -c 5 " + switch)


jobs = [gevent.spawn(print_head, i) for i  in range(1,10)]
gevent.joinall(jobs, timeout=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

`os.system` is not patched, but [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) is patched; Replace `os.system` with `subprocess.call` (You can also use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) if you are using Python 3.5+)

```
import subprocess

...

def print_head(i):
    switch = '192.168.182.170'
    response = subprocess.call("ping " + switch, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `os.system("ping -c 5 " + switch)` is running synchronously, because the function is blocking. You should try to do it in different processes.

Here is a concurrent code that does the same.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def print_head(i):
    switch='192.168.182.170'
    response = os.system("ping -c 5 " + switch)

processes = [Process(target=print_head, args=(i,)) for i in range(1,10)]
for process in processes:
    process.start()
```

Comment: Hey tim, thanks for this solution. but if I  run it for 10000 server, it took near abt 90 seconds . Is there any way I can improve performance on this script that took less then 60 min

Comment: 90 seconds per process?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. if i used code like ---processes = [Process(target=print_head, args=(i,)) for i in range(1,10000)] then it took neat ant 90 sec to finish. is there any way it should get closer to 60 sec.

Comment: Can you try using a pool and map? [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: `from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

def print_head(i):
    switch='192.168.182.170'
    response = os.system("ping -c 5 " + switch)

p = Pool(10)
p.map(print_head, xrange(10))`